Adjust tabular to page width
I generated a simple table using:
\begin{tabular}{m{2cm} m{8.5cm} r{3cm}}
...
\end{tabular}

My question is:
How can I align the third column to the right of my page? Currently, the column moves to the left depending on the width of the second column.

The r column type does not take a width argument. You should be getting a syntax error from r{3cm}.

Try to use tabularx and for third column  use X column type, something like \begin{tabular}x}{\textwidth}{m{2cm} m{8.5cm} >{\raggedleft}X}.

@Zarko - >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X would be better, as the X-column is the third and last column.

@Mico, you are right. I overlooked this ... +1 for your answer !

r{3cm} should be throwing a syntax error. I suggest you load the array package and replace r{3cm} with wr{3cm}.
If, in addition, you want to assure that the table spans the full width of the textblock, I suggest -- as @Zarko has already done in part in a comment -- that you load the tabularx and ragged2e packages in the preamble and write
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} m{2cm} m{8.5cm} >{\RaggedLeft}X @{}}
...
\end{tabularx}

in the body of the document.
